# Relationship between order statistics and equality with uniform distribution

Tags: order-statistics

I have read somewhere (unfortunately I cannot locate the exact text anymore) that there exists an equality in distribution between the order statistics of any continuous distribution and the uniform distribution.

In other words, let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be identically distributed random variables, where $X_{1:n},\ldots,X_{n:n}$ are their order statistics so that $X_{1:n}<\ldots<X_{n:n}$. Then, there exists an equality in distribution

\begin{equation*}
\frac{X_{i:n}}{X_{n:n}}\overset{d}{=} Y_{i:n-1}, \quad \forall 1\leq i\leq n-1
\end{equation*}
where $Y_i\sim \text{Uniform}(0,1)$. In other words, the ratio $\frac{X_{i:n}}{X_{n:n}}$ has supposedly the same distribution as the $i\text{th}$ order statistic of the $n-1$ independent and uniformly distributed random variates $U_1,\ldots,U_{n-1}$. Is this true?

Can we then say that $\frac{X_{1:n}}{X_{n:n}},\ldots,\frac{X_{n-1:n}}{X_{n:n}}$ are i.i.d. and distributed as $\sim \text{Uniform}(0,1)$?

$\textbf{Edit:}$

I managed to track down the text I was thinking of. It is in the book "A First Course in Order Statistics" by Barry C. Arnold , N. Balakrishnan and H. N. Nagaraja. Specifically, I am thinking of equations (2.4.1) and (2.4.2) in Chapter 2, pp. 21-22.

Please have a look on Google Books (I do not want to copy-paste the whole thing due to copyright): [2.4. Some Properties of Order Statistics](https://books.google.se/books?id=gUD-S8USlDwC&lpg=PA9&hl=sv&pg=PA21#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: That seems wrong -- the ratio takes values outside $[0,1]$, the denominator could be concentrated around, zero, ... -- are you sure you don't mean values of the cumulative distribution function? Something along these lines might be true for those (but then again, those values are uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$, so that wouldn't be terribly interesting...)

Comment: Not sure which ratio you mean takes values outside $[0,1]$? Yes, with distribution I mean the CDF.

Comment: I mean the ratio $\frac{X_{i:n}}{X_{n:n}}$. It could take any value, no?

Comment: @joriki By definition, the $(X_{i:n})_{1\leq i\leq n}$ are sorted in non-decreasing order. So all the ratios are (assuming the original $X_i$'s take value in $[0,\infty)$ between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: @ClementC.: But there's no assumption about positivity in the question. Also, even with that assumption, there would be easy counterexample -- for instance a uniform distribution on $[0,1]\cup[9,10]$, where about half of the ratios would be $\gt\frac9{10}$.

Comment: @joriki I never stated the OP's purported statement was true -- just tried to answer your particular point.

Comment: I managed to located the text I was thinking of, see the edit in my original post. Does this help to answer my original question?

Comment: Unfortunately Google Books won't let me look at p. $21$ (p. $22$ is OK) -- could you type out what's important on p. $21$?

Comment: I'm paraphrasing: Let $U_1,\ldots,U_n$ be samples from the standard uniform distribution. Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be samples from a distribution $F(x)$. Let also $U_{1:n}\leq\cdots U_{n:n}$ and $X_{1:n}\leq\cdots X_{n:n}$ be their order statistics. 

When $F(x)$ is continuous, the transformation $U=F(x)$ produces a standard uniform distribution, and we have: $F(X_{i:n})\overset{d}{=}U_{i:n}, i=1,\ldots,n$.

It then follows that: $F^{-1}(U_i)\overset{d}{=}X_{i}, i=1,\ldots,n$. 

Since $F^{-1}(\cdot)$ is order preserving, we finally get: $F^{-1}(U_{i:n})\overset{d}{=}X_{i:n}, i=1,\ldots,n$.

Comment: There's also this blog post (https://ckrao.wordpress.com/2012/05/27/the-distribution-of-xxy-is-uniform-when-x-and-y-are-iid-exponential/): If $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are iid exponential, then for $k<n$ the ratio $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^k X_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}$ has the same distribution as the $k\text{th}$ smallest number out of $(n-1)$ numbers chosen independently and uniformly between 0 and 1.

Comment: @index: Your first (paraphrasing) comment above is basically what I meant by "are you sure you don't mean values of the cumulative distribution function? Something along these lines might be true for those". I think this is quite separate from the result in your second comment above about the exponential distribution. My question at this point is: What's your question at this point? :-)

Comment: @joriki: I tried to clarify this in a comment above: "Not sure which ratio you mean takes values outside [0,1]? Yes, with distribution I mean the CDF." But basically my question is whether $\frac{X_{i:n}}{X_{n:n}}, i<n,$ are i.i.d. and distributed as $\sim\text{Uniform}(0,1)$? And, if not, how do I "make" them become that. I am obviously not grasping something here.